# Mysql error inside folder

Tags: 16.04, mariadb

I am new to Ubuntu I using Ubuntu for development with frappé.But now I am facing problem with MariaDB. My problem is when i type

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I am getting an error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

but when i restart pc and run the above command I am getting no error it is working fine but when I navigate my working folder in home directory and run the command I getting error above and when comeback to desktop and again run this command I am getting same error here also please help me I am s tucked

details of Ubuntu is given below

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p *database*
```